# How many solutions do $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $x^{p-1} \equiv 2 \pmod p$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is my first post so I apologize for any kind of error.

I'm preparing a magistral degree exam in number theory, and I'm performing some exercise. 
I'm asking here this question: how can I prove how many solutions there are for $x^{p-1}  \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $x^{p-1}  \equiv 2 \pmod p$?

Edit: $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Alessar: You may take example for $p$ say $p=5$ to get an intuitive understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know Fermat‘s little theorem?

Consider the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z^\times_p$.

Comment: Yes I know it, this is the same as consider x^{p} \equiv x(mod p), but for the second questions I'm really stuck

Comment: If you know Fermat's Little Theorem, then you would know that, if $p$ is a prime natural number and $x$ is an integer such that $p\nmid x$, then $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  Thus, unless $p=2$, $x^{p-1}\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ has no solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's the first time I study number theory